# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL in WildFly

Tags: java, rest, maven, intellij-idea, wildfly-10

I'm trying to build a Java web-app in Intellij, using Wildfly as Application server.
In my web app, i'm trying to configure a module for restful webservices (with RestEasy library) but when I try to test my restful webservice (as post method), i receive the message "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL".
I don't understand why I see this message...

I launch my rest service as follow:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/email/myName/my@address.com/myMessage
```

In my pom.xml I added the needed library:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my web.xml I added this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Smoney-RS</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myapp.rs.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Finally, my java class for rest api:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/email")
public class EmailRestfulImpl
{

    @POST
    @Path("/{name}/{address}/{message}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendContactUs(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("address") String address, @PathParam("message") String message)
    {
        EmailRequest emailRequest = new EmailRequest();
        emailRequest.setName(name);
        emailRequest.setEmail(address);
        emailRequest.setMessage(message);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(emailRequest).build();

    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you change to this <url-pattern>rest</url-pattern> ??

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue. The context path was not correct.
I was trying to call this:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/email/myName/my@address.com/myMessage
```

The correct path was this:

```
http://localhost:8080/MYAPP-SNAPSHOT-1.0/rest/email/myName/my@address.com/myMessage
```

I solved adding the context-path tag in my jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/rest</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And finally, I added the context-param in my web.xml as follow:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I hope can be helpful for you!